# PHP global variables between tags

Tags: php, global-variables, superglobals

So within my php file I have multiple sets of opening and closing php tags. It basically looks something like this:

```
<input id="myID" type="text" value="<?php 
$value="x";
echo $value;
?>">
<input id="yourID" type="text" value="<?php echo $someValue; ?>"
```

Is there anyway to refer to `$value` in the second set of php brackets? I tried using [GLOBAL['index']](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp) to refer to `$value`, but I get an undefined index error.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You can just use `$value` again.

Comment: `$value` should be in scope for the whole document (taking function scope in to consideration)

Comment: An aside: since you are injecting values from PHP into HTML, you should **always** use `htmlspecialchars`. Read the docs on it, it's important you get the parameters correct and "correct" depends on the context into which you are injecting (e.g. inside a double-quoted attribute value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `echo $value`.

The variable context doesn't change just because you have re-opened the PHP tag.  `<?php` and `?>` are just flags for the parser, and have no bearing on what your code does inside of them.

Since you're just getting started, I also recommend looking into a templating engine such as Smarty.  This will help you separate application logic from your output.  Also, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML, to ensure that reserved characters are escaped, and that you aren't creating any XSS attack points.

Comment: I was doing that originally, but that's were the problem arose in the first place. I was getting an undefined error.

Comment: @Wold It definitely works.  If you show us your code that didn't work, we might be able to make a suggestion.

Comment: I guess my problem must be elsewhere then, I'll look back over my code.

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure what you mean in regard to the XSS attack points, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Wold Suppose I have a page that accepts data in the query string... `/somePage.php?id=12345`.  If in my code I just have `<h1>ID: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></h1>`, then someone could craft a URL that had a script tag in it, loading JavaScript from an external resource which then runs on your page allowing a malicious script to steal data and what not from a logged in user.  If you are properly escaping everything (which you should be doing anyway), this becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's variable scope is function-level. Closing a `<?php ... ?>` code block doesn't change your scope level.

e.g.

```
<html>

<?php $x = 'foo'; ?>

<body>

<?php echo $x; ?>
```

would output `foo` as expected. If you were using functions, then it'd be a different matter:

```
function foo() {
   $x = 'foo';
}
foo();
echo $x;  // undefined variable
```

and that wouldn't change no matter how many/few `<?php ... ?>` code blocks you were using.